# Не срабатывает запрос на обновление

Tags: php, mysqli

Помогите понять почему не работает редактирование и добавление?
В форму данные передаю, но потом не срабатывает имeнно update. 
Возможно логика неверно выстроена?

```html
<body>
  <?php
$host = 'localhost';  
$user = 'root';    
$pass = ''; 
$db_name = 'blog';   
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name); // Соединяемся с базой


if (!$link) {
    echo 'Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
}

//Если переменная передана
if (isset($_POST["title"]))  {
//Если это запрос на обновление, то обновляем
if (isset($_GET['red_id'])) {
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE `articles` SET `title` = '{$_POST['title']}',`content` = '{$_POST['content']}',`date` = '{$_POST['date']}' WHERE `ID`={$_GET['red_id']}");
} else {
//Иначе вставляем данные, подставляя их в запрос
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `articles` (`title`, `content`,`date`) VALUES ('{$_POST['title']}', '{$_POST['content']}','{$_POST['date']}')");
}

//Если вставка прошла успешно
if ($sql) {
echo '<p>Успешно!</p>';
} else {
echo '<p>Произошла ошибка: ' . mysqli_error($link) . '</p>';
}
}

if (isset($_GET['del_id'])) { //проверяем, есть ли переменная
//удаляем строку из таблицы
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM `articles` WHERE `ID` = {$_GET['del_id']}");
if ($sql) {
echo "<p>строка удалена.</p>";
} else {
echo '<p>Произошла ошибка: ' . mysqli_error($link) . '</p>';
}
}

//Если передана переменная red_id, то надо обновлять данные
if (isset($_GET['red_id'])) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `ID`, `title`, `content`,`date` FROM `articles` WHERE `ID`={$_GET['red_id']}");
    $article = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
}
?>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Наименование:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Name" value="<?= isset($_GET['red_id']) ? $article['title'] : ''; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Текст:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="content" value="<?= isset($_GET['red_id']) ? $article['content'] : ''; ?>"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Дата:</td>
          <td><input type="date" name="date" value="<?= isset($_GET['red_id']) ? $article['date'] : ''; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="OK"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <table border='1'>
      <tr>
        <td>Идентификатор</td>
        <td>Заголовок</td>
        <td>Текст</td>
        <td>Дата</td>
        <td>Удаление</td>
        <td>Редактирование</td>
      </tr>
      <?php
    $sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `ID`, `title`, `content`,`date` FROM `articles`');
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo '<tr>' .
            "<td>{$result['ID']}</td>" .
            "<td>{$result['title']}</td>" .
            "<td>{$result['content']} </td>" .
            "<td>{$result['date']} </td>" .
            "<td><a href='?del_id={$result['ID']}'>Удалить</a></td>" .
            "<td><a href='?red_id={$result['ID']}'>Изменить</a></td>" .
            '</tr>';
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <p><a href="?add=new">Добавить новую </a></p>
```

Comment: $_POST[title ] __нигде__ не определяется.

Comment: @u_mulder Я думал в форме он определяется. 
Не затруднило бы более точно подсказать? благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Вроде как отправляешь форму с `post` запросом, потом проверяешь на наличие названия `$_POST["title"]`(в форме отправляешь 'name') и дальше идет проверка к GET запросу `$_GET['red_id']` хотя `red_id` не передаешь.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в форме не передаётся **title**. Вместо этого вы передаёте параметр **Name** в поле Наименование. Должно быть `name="title"`.

Вставлять в запросы данные получаемые от пользователя без обработки это прямой путь к получению SQL инъекции.
Используйте `bind_param`
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
Пример кода с UPDATE:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,"UPDATE `articles` SET `title` = '?',`content` = '?',`date` = '?' WHERE `ID`=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssi', $_POST['title'], $_POST['content'], $_POST['date'], $_POST['red_id']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Comment: то есть нужно наоборот? я считаю так, если данные у меня в форме есть то тогда должно срабатывать условие. Не могли бы более точно меня поправить. Прошу прощения за затуп

Comment: Изменил ответ, переименуйте input из Name в title.

Comment: Подготовленное выражение записано __неправильно__